# Upload image doesn't work

Tags: php, forms, symfony, file-upload

I try to upload an image in form but nothing happens.

user entity (NB: this entity contains others attributes about user informations)

```
<?php

namespace Test\BackBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    ...

   /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $path;

    public $file;

    ... 

    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
       return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
       return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {   
       return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
       return 'upload/files';
    }

   /**
    * @ORM\PrePersist()
    * @ORM\PreUpdate()
    */
   public function preUpload()
   {
      if (null !== $this->file) {
          $this->path = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)).'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
      }
   }

   /**
    * @ORM\PostPersist()
    * @ORM\PostUpdate()
    */
   public function upload()
   {
       if (null === $this->file) {
          return;
       }

       $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);

       unset($this->file);
   }

   /**
    * @ORM\PostRemove()
    */
   public function removeUpload()
   {
       if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
           unlink($file);
       }
   }
}
```

UserType.php:

```
$builder
    ->add('firstName', 'text', array(
                    'required' => true
                ))
     ->add('lastName', 'text', array(
                    'required' => true
                ))
     ->add('email', 'email', array(
                    'required' => true
                ))
     ->add('job', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false
                ))
     ->add('file', 'file', array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'required' => false,
                    'mapped' => false
                ))
     ;
```

UserController.php

```
    public function updateMyAccountAction($id, Request $request)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();

        $user = $this->get('doctrine')
            ->getRepository('TestBackBundle:User')
            ->find($id);

        if (!$user) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find User entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);

        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {

            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('my_account', array('id' => $id)));
        }
    }
```

my_account.html.twig:

```
<form action="{{ path('my_account_update', { 'id': app.user.id }) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
   {{ form_widget(form) }}

   <div class="btn-group">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Enregistrer</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

When I submit my form, I have no error but the image is not uploaded.

**EDIT:**

If I remove `'mapped' => false` from builder, I have this error :

> Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile'
>   is not allowed

If I do a `var_dump($user)` after validation, path attribute = NULL

Comment: What does the generated html look like? is there a proper `enctype` attribute in the `<form>` tag?

Comment: `<form action="/app_dev.php/admin/dashboard/my_account/1/update" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Can you access files from $request in this action? Like this : $files = $request->files;

Comment: Yes I can access to it

Comment: And see something in it ? Maybe filename or something like this ?

Comment: Yes I see all the information of the file like originalName for example

Comment: Your file is uploaded ? because you never call the upload() function into your updateMyAccountAction()...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52047/discussion-between-perroin-thibault-and-doz)

Comment: When you update your entity are you modifying only the file ?

Comment: no I can update others informations about the user

Comment: Ok, but to test your function, have you modified another element that the file ? Because the doc says : "The PreUpdate and PostUpdate callbacks are only triggered if there is a change in one of the entity's fields that are persisted."

Comment: I have test both, but nothing happens

Comment: Strange, maybe LifecycleCallbacks doesn't work good... I've u test with Assert/File ?

Comment: yes... `/**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    public $file;`

Comment: I dropped callbacks to use instead only an upload function in my entity and it works.

Comment: Yes, I think there is a problem with files and callbacks... Maybe someone will have another solution

Comment: For me, file uploading requires more front end design so I used a separate bundle that can work with other javascript libraries.  This way the user gets feedback during the upload process and is easy to add your own functionality after the upload has taken place (move it, rename it, etc).  [OneupUploader Bundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle)

Answer (score 0):

I can give simple code to upload an image of file :)

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{

    if ($this->image instanceof UploadedFile && $this->image != null && $this->image->getRealPath()) {
        $dir = "photos/";
        $name = md5(rand().time()) . "." . $this->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $this->image->move($dir, $name);
        $this->setImage($dir.$name);
    };
}
```